# Python: How to Add Specificly Characterized text To A Text File

Tags: python, string, file, ubuntu, editing

I am writing a program using the Python Programming Language. 
Here is a part of my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import time
import sys

print "Creating new text file"
file = open("launcher_profiles.json",'w')
file.write('{
  "profiles": {
    "MODS 7.10": {
      "name": "Forge",
      "lastVersionId": "mods7.10"
    },
    "Forge": {
      "name": "Forge"
    },
    "mods": {
      "name": "mods",
      "lastVersionId": "mods"
    }
  },
  "selectedProfile": "Forge",
  "clientToken": "e1a07b41-8e41-44b5-9781-3dd3a201bf30",
  "authenticationDatabase": {
    "6d63772c9c4141e2908049dd833d9cc4": {
      "username": "Marc",
      "accessToken": "df914be0efcc4f16aedb532d85b9d939",
      "userid": "25065109",
      "uuid": "6d63772c-9c41-41e2-9080-49dd833d9cc4",
      "displayName": "Marc"
    }
  },
  "selectedUser": "6d63772c9c4141e2908049dd833d9cc4",
  "launcherVersion": {
    "name": "1.5.2",
    "format": 17
  }
}')
file.close()
```

The error I get:

```
    marc@Mezex:~/MineCrack$ ./MineCrack.py
      File "./MineCrack.py", line 9
        file.write('{
```

I am writing a program that upon startup of minecraft, some files are changed. One file that needs to be changed is "launcher_profiles.json". All I need to do is overwrite the text inside the document with:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MODS 7.10": {
      "name": "Forge",
      "lastVersionId": "mods7.10"
    },
    "Forge": {
      "name": "Forge"
    },
    "mods": {
      "name": "mods",
      "lastVersionId": "mods"
    }
  },
  "selectedProfile": "Forge",
  "clientToken": "e1a07b41-8e41-44b5-9781-3dd3a201bf30",
  "authenticationDatabase": {
    "6d63772c9c4141e2908049dd833d9cc4": {
      "username": "Marc",
      "accessToken": "df914be0efcc4f16aedb532d85b9d939",
      "userid": "25065109",
      "uuid": "6d63772c-9c41-41e2-9080-49dd833d9cc4",
      "displayName": "Marc"
    }
  },
  "selectedUser": "6d63772c9c4141e2908049dd833d9cc4",
  "launcherVersion": {
    "name": "1.5.2",
    "format": 17
  }
}
```

I need the text to be exactly like that, the spaces, and line changes included.

Comment: You might want to take a look at parsing json with python.

Comment: That's not the whole error message.

Comment: It would help if you included the *entire* error message, including, "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string is a multi-line string. In Python, you use `'''` or `"""` to delimit multiline strings[*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Change your `file.write()` to look like this:

```
file.write('''{
    blah, blah
    blah
''')
```

Comment: Might want to mention the option of just copying over the existing file.

Comment: That would be a better comment, I think, than an answer. I took OP's question to be, "Why do I get this error message?", not "How do I maintain Minecraft's startup files?"